# Mysql STR_TO_DATE incorrect datetime value

Tags: mysql, datetime

I've loaded some date from file to table and now i want to convert the string with date to a datetime format. 
The string i 'datestring' column looks like this '12-16-2010 01:48:28', and if i run this query:

```
select STR_TO_DATE('12-16-2010 01:48:28', '%c-%e-%Y %T')
```

It returns proper datetime: `2010-12-16 01:48:28`

But when i try to run this:

```
update database.`temptable` 
SET datetimefile = (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(datestring, '%c-%e-%Y %T'))
```

I get those kind of errors:

```
Incorrect datetime value: ''12-16-2010 01:48:28'' for function str_to_date
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48503845/746347).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a close look at the error message:

```
Incorrect datetime value: ''12-16-2010 01:48:28''
                          ^^  2 single quotes  ^^
```

Compare this to the normal error message:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('foo', '%c-%e-%Y %T');
+-----------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('foo', '%c-%e-%Y %T') |
+-----------------------------------+
| NULL                              |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                  |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: 'foo' for function str_to_date |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)                      ^   ^ just 1 single quote
```

Normally, the error message has a single set of single quotes.  Yours has a double set, suggesting that you actually have a set of single quotes stored in your column data.

If this is the case, you can work around this by removing them where they exist:

```
SET datetimefile = (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(datestring,"'",''), '%c-%e-%Y %T'))
```

Using [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) like this still would work even if not all of the rows contain the spurious quotes, since replace passes through the input value unchanged if the 'from_str' (2nd arg) doesn't occur.

Comment: Yes, figured it out :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From PHP SQL Request Correct:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '.$filename."' INTO TABLE tablename (@var_DTime, `Product`, `Source`, `Cost`) SET `DTime` = str_to_date(@var_DTime,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s')
```

---

Do not use: " " - 2010-12-31 01:48:28; - Don't work

---

Use "T" - 2010-12-31T01:48:28; - Work

Comment: Space works fine here.  Also, `STR_TO_DATE()` wouldn't be very useful if it couldn't conform to the input format of what could be a very large input file.  `2010-12-31T01:48:28` is ISO 8601 format, but you can't expect random external input to conform to that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem,
I wanted to use order by date syntax, but since my dates were in text format it returned the table unsorted.
I tried using

```
Alter table 
 Alter column `column name` date
```

but it gave the me same error you've got.

the only solution that I found by trial and error was to change the format of the date in the CSV file. I changed it to YYYY-MM-DD, then used "Alter table , alter column `column name`" to change the data type in the column

Answer (score 0):

This error happened when you are trying to add a **non-DateTime** value inside a **DateTime** column.

For example, the DateTime format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. So in any case, if you try to add a date with any format other than the original format, it will throw this error.

In my case, I was using `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load a CSV file, to a specific table. One of the columns in the CSV file was in another date format, so I was supposed to change the format using **str_to_date** function using the below syntax:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'x.csv'
INTO TABLE orders FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(
     timimg,
     order_id,
     order_details
)
set timing= STR_TO_DATE(lower(@timing), '%d-%b-%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

The above syntax throws the same error (Incorrect DateTime value for function str_to_date), So **what was the issue**?.

It was just adding the **@** for the `timing` column. **@** character means that you are telling MySQL to not load the data directly in the table for that column, however, make some changes to the value from CSV before inserting in the table.

So by adding the character **@** in the above query, It fixes the issue. The correct syntax is:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'x.csv'
INTO TABLE orders FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(
      @timimg,
      order_id,
      order_details
)
set timing= STR_TO_DATE(lower(@timing), '%d-%b-%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
... SET datetimefile = STR_TO_DATE(datestring, '%c-%e-%Y-%T')
```

Note the lack of `select` around the str_to_date call. That select had no table reference, so the query failed with "unknown field datestring". That failure bubbled upwards and killed the entire overall query.