# mySQL str_to_date() function returns error

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I keep receiving an error message when trying to convert a column, CreatedDate, of string date values in my Estimates table into the mySQL date format using str_to_date(). My column of data contains dates in m/d/yy format (for example: 1/26/16 or 3/3/16).

I ran this query:

```
UPDATE Estimates
SET CreatedDate = str_to_date( CreatedDate, '%c/%e/%y' )
```

mySQL is returning this error message:

```
Error
SQL query:
UPDATE Estimates
SET CreatedDate = str_to_date( CreatedDate, '%c/%e/%y' )
MySQL said: #1411 - Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date
```

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Do you have rows where this field is empty?

Comment: Ideally you should create a new `DATE` type column then switch from the old string value to the new `DATE` one using this function. You'll also have to skip those values that are blank or `NULL`. Internally MySQL prefers ISO-8601 formatted dates: YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: @tadman How can I adjust my query to account for the values that are NULL? If I create a new DATE type column, what is the query to convert the values from CreatedDate to the correct date format and move them to the new column? Thank you for your help!

Comment: why not just change the null values to '00/00/0000' ?  if you want to keep them as nulls use the case statement

Comment: @LizBanach NULL or empty ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual strategy for cleaning up data like this is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE Estimates CHANGE COLUMN CreatedDate CreatedDateString VARCHAR(255);
ALTER TABLE Estimates ADD COLUMN CreatedDate DATE

UPDATE Estimates SET CreatedDate=STR_TO_DATE(CreatedDateString, '%c/%e/%y'))
  WHERE CreatedDateString IS NOT NULL AND CreatedDateString != ''
```

Then when you're confident everything got converted correctly:

```
ALTER TABLE Estimates DROP COLUMN CreatedDateString
```

The advantage to proper `DATE` fields is they're in a consistent format and when you add an `INDEX` on them data retrieval is very fast, even on ranges, like:

```
SELECT * FROM Estimates WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-06-30'
```

Answer (score 4):

Disable [`NO_ZERO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) SQL mode:

```
set @old_sql_mode = @@sql_mode; 
set sql_mode = '';
```

Run your statement:

```
UPDATE Estimates
SET CreatedDate = NULLIF(str_to_date(CreatedDate, '%c/%e/%y'), FROM_DAYS(0))
```

Then enable original SQL modes:

```
set sql_mode = @old_sql_mode;
```

Disabling `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode will make `STR_TO_DATE` return zero date `0000-00-00` for invalid date strings, the same value is returned by `FROM_DAYS(0)`. So `NULLIF` will convert zero dates to `NULL`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19687734/746347) was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It's hitting blank values in your column.

```
SET CreatedDate = str_to_date( '', '%c/%e/%y' )
```

I think this outputs 0000-00-00 and that works as an invalid date if you are setting a date field to that.

```
SET CreatedDate = STR_TO_DATE( IFNULL(case when CreatedDate = '' then null else createddate end,'1901-1-1'), '%c/%e/%y' )
```

That will leave 1901-01-01 values for nulls and blank

Added to tadman:

```
SET CreatedDate = STR_TO_DATE(case when CreatedDate = '' then null else createddate end, '%c/%e/%y' )
```

Nulls instead of 1901-01-01 if you prefer.

Comment: Putting in junk dates is bad form. This is how people end up being pegged as being 115 years old. If it's blank or `NULL`, set it to `NULL`.

Comment: @tadman - alternate added to leave nulls instead of the 1901-01-01, hopefully addresses the dv

Comment: Now we're talking. Thanks. You can also use the `IF(...)` function when your `CASE` has only one case.

Comment: I got this error message:

`Error
SQL query:

UPDATE Estimates
SET CreatedDate = STR_TO_DATE(case when CreatedDate = '' then null else createddate end, '%c/%e/%y' )
MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'CreatedDate' in 'field list'`

Comment: @LizBanach - does the column createddate in the estimates table exist?