# #1411 - Incorrect datetime value: '11:21:21' for function str_to_date

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I don't understand why the date format is incorrect:

```
INSERT INTO ticks (idticks, symbol, date, time, size, type) VALUES (
    1,
    'EUR-USD', 
    STR_TO_DATE('10-04-2017', '%d-%m-%Y'), 
    STR_TO_DATE('11:21:21', '%h:%i:%s'), 
    1.656, 
    'askbid');
```

MySQL answers : 
**#1411 - Incorrect datetime value: '11:21:21' for function str_to_date**

Thank for you help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql STR\_TO\_DATE incorrect datetime value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219552/mysql-str-to-date-incorrect-datetime-value)

Comment: Nope not a dup.  that one has quotes stored in db.  that's clearly not the case here.

Comment: That's strange indeed, looks ok to me...

Comment: What's the data type of 'time' column?

Comment: Works on a SQL fiddle version 5.6 of mySQL... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b15c4/1  assuming date for date and time for time data types.  Thus implying it's a version or config issue in your db; or with the driver passing the query to mySQL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@xQbert - This is not a error in Version 5.7 !!!!!
In Version 5.7 is the **sql_mode** set with **NO_ZERO_IN_DATE**
and this means that only valid dates are accepted. if you remove them
all is working like 5.6

**sample**

```
mysql>   INSERT INTO ticks (idticks, symbol, DATE, `time`, size, TYPE) VALUES (
    ->     1,
    ->     'EUR-USD',
    ->     STR_TO_DATE('10-04-2017', '%d-%m-%Y'),
    ->     STR_TO_DATE('11:21:21', '%h:%i:%s'),
    ->
    ->     1.656,
    ->     'askbid');
ERROR 1411 (HY000): Incorrect datetime value: '11:21:21' for function str_to_date
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                                                                                                                     |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sql_mode      | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,02 sec)

mysql> SET sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO ticks (idticks, symbol, DATE, `time`, size, TYPE) VALUES (     1,     'EUR-USD',      STR_TO_DATE('10-04-2017', '%d-%m-%Y'),      STR_TO_DATE('11:21:21', '%h:%i:%s'),           1.656,      'askbid');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thank for you help, i couldn't find the solution by myself.